# How to pin file to Pinata and also pin json to Pinata using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, upload, pinata

I am just wandering arround to find a way to pin the file to Pinata

Though I have a method to do it from server side but don't know how to do it from client side like React.js:

This is server side method

```js
async function storeImages(imagesFilePath) {
  const fullImagesPath = path.resolve(imagesFilePath);
  const files = fs.readdirSync(fullImagesPath);
  let responses = [];
  console.log("Uploading to Pinata !!!");
  console.log("paths ", fs.createReadStream(fullImagesPath + "/" + files[0]));
  for (fileIndex in files) {
    const readableStreamForFile = fs.createReadStream(
      `${fullImagesPath}/${files[fileIndex]}`
    );
    try {
      const response = await pinata.pinFileToIPFS(readableStreamForFile);
      responses.push(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
  return { responses, files };
}
async function storeTokeUriMetadata(metadata) {
  try {
    const response = await pinata.pinJSONToIPFS(metadata);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Pinata home page:
[Pinata home page with some manually uploaded files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u9h8.png)

Would appreciate to help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this component a while back, hope it’s still helpful! :)

```
import { useState } from "react"
import axios from "axios" 

const FileUpload = () => {

  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState();

  const changeHandler = (event) => {
    setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
  };

  const handleSubmission = async() => {

    const formData = new FormData();
    
    formData.append('file', selectedFile)

    const metadata = JSON.stringify({
      name: 'File name',
    });
    formData.append('pinataMetadata', metadata);

    try{
      const res = await axios.post("https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS", formData, {
        maxBodyLength: "Infinity",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`,
          Authorization: `Bearer PASTE_YOUR_JWT_HERE`,
        }
      });
      console.log(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
    <label class="form-label">Choose File</label>
    <input type="file"  onChange={changeHandler}/>
    <button onClick={handleSubmission}>Submit</button>
    </>
  )
}

export default FileUpload
```